# How to pass object from one Onsen UI page to another?

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a js object loaded on one Onsen UI masterpage, when I called 
**ons.navigator.pushPage('child_page.html')**
how can I get the js object on the child page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the documentation and guides.

http://onsenui.io/guide/overview.html#PageNavigation

You can get objects via the following methods:

page1

```
myNavigator.pushPage("page2.html", { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" });
```

page2

```
var page = myNavigator.getCurrentPage();
console.log(page.options.param1); // Will return "value1"
```

Comment: I am having the same issue,and i used this answer working perfect but only for one parameter passing,When i am trying to pass second parameter it is not working.

Comment: Note this is the answer for OnsenUI version 1. For Version 2 see the answer by @morteza_tourani below. The link given in this answer by Ataru does not work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

In OnsenUI 2 you can access like this:

```
var options = myNavigator.topPage.pushedOptions;
```

I tried [ataru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3463511/ataru)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236779/3078890) but didn't work for me, I think this is because of the `RC Version` hope they fix this or at least change their documentation about it.

Comment: I use `var nav = document.querySelector('#navigator');` I can then do `nav.popPage()` but there is no attribute `nav.topPage`!!  I see only THIS page's pushedOptions which are `animation` related. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @pashute My answer is for long time ago when I tried `Onsen` for a while, but now I'm using `Ionic` due to company policies and since that moment forward `Onsen` has taken lot's of great steps. All I told means I'm not a good one to ask anymore and I'm sorry.

Comment: It seems I had some mistake in the code, that caused the nav not to evaluate. So your answer did in fact work for me. Thanks so much!! (I upvoted your answer)